# Resolving multiple domain names to different virtual machines on the same WAN IP

Tags: dns, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am running a couple of VMs on my LAN (using proxmox) and I have a single External IP. 
I have 2 domains and I have them setup to resolve to my External IP.

Question: I would like to do the following

1. point www.myfirstdomain.com to come VM1 at port 80
2. point www.mysecondomain.com to VM2 at port 80

I haven't been able to find a solution to this specific scenario. Any pointers will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something that understands HTTP, i. e. something that operates at OSI Layer 7.  The only way I know to do that is to have something like an HTTP load balancer in front of your VM's, then have your VM's on some sort of private (e. g. 192.168.1.0/24) IP space behind that load balancer (LB).  The LB will then interpret the HTTP URL and direct HTTP sessions to the appropriate VM.

Personally, the way I do it is just run both URL's on a single Apache instance using VirtualHosts.  It's actually pretty secure to do it that way, and it's the "time honored" way to run multiple Web sites on a single WAN IP address.